# AngularJS working with ng-change in a directive with isolated scope - Moving to component based architecture

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently fighting to get ng-change to fire in my directive with a isolated scope. Im trying to move away from ng-controller to a more component based architecture yet it is proving more challenging than expected.

Here is a fiddle that I can't seem to get working.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erniedebruin/mmz3pvcn/)

I'm pretty sure the issue lies somewhere in here

```
app.directive("search", function(service) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.search = function(keyword) {
                service.searchData(keyword);
            };
        }],
        template: '<div style="padding-bottom: 15px;">' +
                            '<center>' +
                '<input type="text" ng-model="keyword" ng-change="search(keyword)"/>' +
               '</center>' +
                            '</div>'
    };
});
```

But the fiddle will give a more complete idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chnage controllers as shown below

`controller: searchCtrl`

write the below code outside of directive

```
 searchCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'service'];
 function searchCtrl($scope, service) {
    $scope.search = function(keyword) {
       alert("called - " + keyword);
       service.searchData(keyword);
    };
}
```

Comment: This works in triggering the service call, but now once triggered it runs on every digest cycle until the maximum call stack is exceeded. I have moved to a codepen that actually run the code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqzwJB

Comment: There is some problem in your factory, I hope so

Comment: As shown in my answer, that is one of the correct ways to call a controller from directive if the controller need dependency injection. Otherwise we can't inject dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Charan Cherry answer is correct if just using angular, but I'm using angular and requireJS together so here is what I did to fix the issue.

Since ng-change didn't fire I just used ng-model and then have a watcher watch for changes and then fire my search function.

Hope this helps someone.